# JQUERY Accordion Menu with tabs opening

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

The code is for generated a home page with two div's: 'left_menu' and 'right_menu', where I want to navigate with the links from left_menu should display the content on the right_menu.

I have two links (reports and roles) on the left_menu and two tabs (tab1 and tab2) on the right_menu.

1. When I click on reports, it should open the tab1 and clicking on
   users should open the tab2.
2. When I launch home.php, the first item(reports) should be opened by
   default and the tab1 accordingly.

Here is the my code I tried, when I click the roles on left_menu, it is opening the default one i.e. tab1 and the left_menu isn't opened by default.

home.php

```
<html lang="<?php echo _SITE_LANGUAGE ?>">
   <head>   
    <script src="../js/jqueryv1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       //accordion left menu
       $ (document).ready(function()
       {
          $ (".wings").click(function(event)
          {
             $(".box").slideUp("slow");
             if ($(this).next().is(":hidden") == true)
             {
                $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
             }
          });
          //(".box").hide("slow");
       });

       //Tab (rightbox)
       $(document).ready(function() 
       {    
         $('#tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
         $('.contain').hide();
         $('.contain:first').show();

         $('#tabs li a').click(function()
         {
            var t = $(this).attr('id');
            if($(this).hasClass('inactive'))
            { //this is the start of our condition 
              $('#tabs li a').addClass('inactive');         
              $(this).removeClass('inactive');
              $('.contain').hide();
              $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
            }
         });
       });

      </script>
    <style>
      .wings { width:200px; float:left; padding:7px 11px; }
      .box { width:195px; float:left; display:none; margin:0px 20px; }
    </style>
   </head>

   <body>
     <?php
        echo '<div class="left_menu">

               <div class="wings">
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="images/right_arrow.gif"/></div>
                <div style="float:left;padding:0px 7px;"><a href="display.php"><a href="report.php">Reports</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;"><img src="images/downarrow.png" style="width:17px;height:17px;cursor:pointer;"/></div>
               </div>

               <div class="box">';
                $reports = $reports->get_report();
                $reports_count = count($reports);
                if ($reports_count > 0 ) {
                   foreach ($reports as $ds)
                   {
                      echo '<div style="float:left;margin:5px 14px;width:180px;">
                               <div style="float:left;"><img src="images/right_arrow.png"></div>
                               <div style="float:left;padding:0px 6px;">'.$ds['dsource_name'].'</img></div>
                               <div style="float:left;"><a href="edit_dsource.php?id='.$ds['id'].'"><img src="images/edit.gif"/></a></div>
                               <div style="float:left;padding:1px 2px;"><img src="images/not-available.png"/></div>                           
                            </div>';
                   }
                }
                else
                echo 'No Datasources';  
               echo '</div>

               <div class="wings">
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="images/right_arrow.gif"/></div>
                <div style="float:left;padding:0px 7px;"><a href="display.php"><a href="report.php">Roles</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;"><img src="images/downarrow.png" style="width:17px;height:17px;cursor:pointer;"/></div>
               </div>

               <div class="box">';
                $roles = $roles->get_report();
                $roles_count = count($roles);
                if ($roles_count > 0 ) {
                   foreach ($roles as $ds)
                   {
                      echo '<div style="float:left;margin:5px 14px;width:180px;">
                               <div style="float:left;"><img src="images/right_arrow.png"></div>
                               <div style="float:left;padding:0px 6px;">'.$ds['dsource_name'].'</img></div>
                               <div style="float:left;"><a href="edit_dsource.php?id='.$ds['id'].'"><img src="images/edit.gif"/></a></div>
                               <div style="float:left;padding:1px 2px;"><img src="images/not-available.png"/></div>                           
                            </div>';
                   }
                }
                else
                echo 'No Datasources';  
               echo '</div>';

        echo '</div> <!--left_menu-->';  

        echo '<div class="right_menu">
               <ul id="tabs">
                  <li><a id="tab1">Configuration</a></li>     
                  <li><a id="tab2">Report Viewer</a></li>
               </ul>

               <div class="container" id="tab1C">
                  <div id="content" style="padding-left:35px;"><h3><font color="brown"> </font><br>
                     ( Report Tab content )               
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="container" id="tab2C">
                  <div id="content" style="padding-left:35px;"><h3><font color="brown"> </font><br>
                     ( Report Tab content )               
                  </div>
               </div>';                  
        echo '</div><!--right_menu-->';
    ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gansai/s9NvX/1/

Comment: so is the page supposed to load when the reports / user is clicked ?

Comment: Yes Pawal..thats it..Thank You

Comment: Pawal: I have given a JS fiddle too. Kindly give me your suggestion

Comment: Could anyone suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague and the fiddle is of little help because the code is obscure.

If you would like page elements to be preconfigured on page load, you should:

1. Have links to the page contain GET parameters (aka [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)) representing elements state. For example:

   ```
   <a href="report.php&tab=1">Reports</a>
   ```
2. Have elements read GET parameters on initialization and apply configuration. Solution:

   [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)